# String lower speed in mac and windows

Tags: c++, string, windows, macos, performance

Hello i have a program in c++ which add Hello world (50000000) times in front of string and i want to see toke how long. this is my source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str2("Hello");
    auto start_t = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50000000; i++) str2 += "Hello";
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_t).count() << " milliseconds\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

i checked this source in 3 Different situations:

**Situation 1:**

```
os: windows
ide: clion (latest version)
MinGW: 5
CMAKE: 3.8.2
GDB: 7.11.1
c++: 17
compile: Release
```

and i got this result:

### **3100 milliseconds**

**Situation 2:**

```
os: windows
ide: vistual studio 2017
compile: Release
```

and i got this result:

### **700 milliseconds**

**Situation 3:**

```
os: MAC OSX
ide: clion (latest version)
CMAKE: 3.8.2
GDB: 7.11.1
c++: 17
compile: Release
```

and i got this result:

### **1200 milliseconds**

i checked on windows and mac and i got this results... why? why the result are totally different? all the situations (Release mode and ...) are same!

Comment: Different operating systems, different compiler on all. You can't really compare them like that. Try to check all three compilers on one system. Or all three systems using one compiler. And if you use different compilers, make sure that the flags (especially for optimizations) are as equal as possible for all compilers.

Comment: Try preallocating 250,000,005 buffer for the string

Comment: In addition to what @Someprogrammerdude said you are also using different machines.

Comment: to do a more fair comparison of std::string implementations, instead of evaluating absolute timings, you may compare the ratio of the timings relative to an equivalent std::vector based code ( with and without reserve )...

Comment: Are these tests even on the same *type* of hardware?

Comment: a little yes ... tests are in same hardware ..

Comment: Note that you don't put `Hello` in **front** of `str2`. You append it to the back. This makes a **huge** difference. Try timing `str2 = "Hello" + str2` as well.

Comment: If you gave us the disassembly for each case, we'd have something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisson has no stable basis.

You are comparing your code on different operating systems, with different compilers.

In order for a comparison to actually take place, you need to keep something fixed. For example, you could check with all three compilers in one system, OR in all three systems with one compiler.

Furthermore, try to use the same optimization flags on every compiler, so that they optimize the code in similar fashion.

Comment: not diffrent compilers ! (clion) ... i used clion (cmake) in windows and mac ! both was in same situation !

Comment: @Samethings clion is an IDE, **not** a compiler!

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.